# FIll the conditional dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iterator, conditional-statements

I was wondering how I can fill the dataframe with certain condition from the other dataset.

`df =pd.DataFrame([[4.3, 2.3,1.3,7.1,7.2], [1.3,2.3,4.5,3.5, 1.2],  [0.5,6.3,3.2,2.1, 0.8], [0.3,1.3,2.7, 0.2,5.2]], columns=['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'])`

`df`

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4.3 | 2.3 | 1.3 | 7.1 | 7.2 |
| 1.3 | 2.3 | 4.5 | 3.5 | 1.2 |
| 0.5 | 6.3 | 3.2 | 2.1 | 0.8 |
| 0.3 | 1.3 | 2.7 | 0.2 | 5.2 |

And condition is something like:

`condition = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0,0,1,0], [0,0,1,0,1], [0,1,0, 0,0], [0,0,0, 0,0]], columns=['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'])`

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | **1** | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | **1** | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | **1** | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

And I would like to update values in `df`, so that if 1 occures the value is changed to a value from the another dataframe `random_number` and all the next columns are 0.0.

If we assume that

`random_number = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,200,size=(4, 5)), columns=list('01234'))`

The update should look something like:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4.3 | 2.3 | 1.3 | **rd** | **0** |
| 1.3 | 2.3 | **rd** | **0** | **0** |
| 0.5 | **rd** | **0** | **0** | **0** |
| 0.3 | 1.3 | 2.7 | 0.2 | 5.2 |

Where **rd** represents the values from the random_numbers dataset.

And how it could be without **rd** - only zeros after the condition is fullfilled?

Thanks!

Comment: The updated dataframe on row 1 column 4 is 0 not rd? Could you explain this?

Comment: Yeah, thanks for pointing out. I wasn't clear enough. Even if 1 can occur later, only first appearance matter. So only the first time should be entered **rd** and 0 until the end, even if 1 comes again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to only keep the first 1 in each row

```py
m = (condition.astype(bool)
     .apply(lambda row: row.mask(row & row.duplicated(), False), axis=1))

out = (df.mask(m.cumsum(axis=1).astype(bool), 0)
       .mask(m, 'rd')) # or replace 'rd' with random_number in your post
```

```
print(m)

       0      1      2      3      4
0  False  False  False   True  False
1  False  False   True  False  False
2  False   True  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False  False

print(out)

     0    1    2    3    4
0  4.3  2.3  1.3   rd  0.0
1  1.3  2.3   rd  0.0  0.0
2  0.5   rd  0.0  0.0  0.0
3  0.3  1.3  2.7  0.2  5.2
```